# Playing MediaElements one after another UWP

Tags: c#, windows, win-universal-app

I have a List containing the `MediaElements` I want to play one after another, but they are playing simultaneously. What is the most efficient way to achieve this?

My code:

```
  foreach (MediaElement m in MediaList)
                {
                    m.Play();
                }
```

Comment: There is a [Sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/e13cf5dca497ad661706d150a154830666913be4/Samples/VideoPlayback) play video one after another in Scenario7 that use  `MediaPlaybackList`.

Answer (score 1):

You can utilize `MediaEnded` event. Not an elegant way, but will do the job. E.g.

```
foreach (var m in MediaList)
{
    m.MediaEnded += MediaElement_MediaEnded;
}
```

Event handler:

```
private void MediaElement_MediaEnded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
      // Play next MediaElement from list
      if (currentMediaIndex < MediaList.Count - 1)
        {
            MediaList[currentMediaIndex + 1].Play();
            currentMediaIndex++;
        }

        // Or start from 0
        else
        {
            currentMediaIndex = 0;
            MediaList[currentMediaIndex].Play();
        }
}
```

Define

```
int currentMediaIndex = 0;
```

and play the first `MediaElement`

```
MediaList[0].Play();
```

Comment: Something is wrong, since it plays them simultaneously.

Comment: I checked and the MediaEnded event is not firing, no idea why.

Comment: I've updated code. Did you define `MediaElement`s in code behind?

Comment: Yes I have other MediaElements besides this list. I didn't notice any change in your code.

Comment: Forgot to tell you that as soon as you assign `Source` property of `MediaElement`, it starts automatically. You need to set `AutoPlay` to `false` for every `MediaElement` except the first one.

Comment: Changed `if` clause in `MediaElement_MediaEnded`

Comment: If i set AutoPlay to false they won't play even when I write `MediaList[1].Play();`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: That's because the associated media isn't loaded yet. Use `MediaOpened` event. Please start chat if there's still any confusion.